# Search-mailbox dynamic date

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm new and hopefully someone can help me!

I have to delete emails which are older than x months and have `subject:test` Im getting crazy with powershell, here is the problem:

```
$time  = (Get-Date).AddDays(33).ToShortDateString()
$Varible = "test"
$Search = [scriptblock]::create("{received<=$($till) AND subject:$Varible}")

echo $search 
## Result: 'received<=9/1/2018 AND subject:1234'
```

> 1)  -> not working(itemcount 0)

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity s@test.at -searchquery "$($search)" -DeleteContent
```

> 2) working:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity s@test.at -searchquery {received<=9/1/2018 AND subject:test} -DeleteContent
```

The varible search is exactly the output what it is set in the search mailbox 1 row above.

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

`-SearchQuery` needs `String`, not `ScriptBlock` ([check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps)):

> The SearchQuery parameter specifies a search string or a query formatted using Keyword Query Language (KQL).

Therefore your query should look like this:

```
[string]$Search = "received<=$time AND subject:$Varible"
```

---

Also, few other remarks specific to the code you provided:

- you mixed two variables: you assigned the date to `$time` and used `$till` in your query
- as [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) mentioned in comments (now deleted) `AddDays(33)` will produce future date, what you should use is `AddDays(-33)`
- usually, converting date to `String` is usually not good practice as you cannot perform other operations on it. However, in that particular case, converting is OK as you finally provide `String` to the command

Answer (score 0):

Hy, try using supported date intervals:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference
Table 4. Date interval reserved keywords

Name of date interval   Description

today
    Represents the time from the beginning of the current day until the end of the current day.

yesterday
    Represents the time from the beginning of the day until the end of the day that precedes the current day.

this week
    Represents the time from the beginning of the current week until the end of the current week. The culture in which the query text was formulated is taken into account to determine the first day of the week.

this month
    Represents the time from the beginning of the current month until the end of the current month.

last month
    Represents the entire month that precedes the current month.

this year
    Represents the time from the beginning of the current year until the end of the current year.

last year
    Represents the entire year that precedes the current year.

```
-SearchQuery 'sent:"last month"'
```